# When I try to Publish it gives error: "could not find file" for most .xml files

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, github, publish

I am trying to publish my .Net MVC project and when I try to do this I get an error mentioning:

> Error    1   Copying file bin\Newtonsoft.Json.xml to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.xml failed. Could not find file 'bin\Newtonsoft.Json.xml.

and this error comes for almost all

> .xml

files in my bin, like:

> System.Web.MVC.xml, System.Web.Helpers.xml, System.Web.Razor.xml,
>   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.xml

I found something relating  [here]:[Build succeeds, but publish fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903337/build-succeeds-but-publish-fail)

but couldn't really understand the solution.And yes I am using git hub
Can anyone help?

Thanx in advance....

Comment: you should have `Newtonsoft.Json.xml` in your bin

Comment: Initially this file was not there when I got this error, then I added this file.But when I rebuild the solution and try to publish again I get this same error

Comment: Remove reference for netonsoft.json and add it again

Comment: @CijoVJ, did you find its solution, I am also getting the same error and couldn't figure out how to resolve?

Comment: @CijoVJ did you get solution of this error? I too this error on my project.