# Project building but not publishing

Tags: visual-studio

I have a strange error my project will build but not publish its complaining about a file missing however the file is there on disk its in my cs project file fine its build action is also set to compile.

in the cs project file

```
 <Compile Include="DevExpress\ASPxSchedulerForms\AppointmentForm.ascx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AppointmentForm.ascx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>

<Compile Include="DevExpress\ASPxSchedulerForms\AppointmentForm.ascx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>AppointmentForm.ascx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

It is there before the desginer file as it should it also physically exists on the disk im going out of my mind here as to what else could be there are no other warnings.

It is also in the visual studio solution file fine and its set build action to compile and its physically there on disk.

The exact error is but the file is phsyically there and in the csproject file as shown above.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The file
>   '/DevExpress/ASPxSchedulerForms/AppointmentForm.ascx.cs' does not
>   exist.    ApertureNet /DevExpress/ASPxSchedulerForms/AppointmentForm.ascx 1

Here is a screen shot of the file in my solution please help 
https://snag.gy/CumGx5.jpg

I dont beleive this to be a specific devexpress issue but more a visual studio complination issue.

Comment: have you gone through so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903337/build-succeeds-but-publish-fails

Comment: @AnilKumar YES Kumar that was one of the first posts i came across but to no avail

Comment: This may be due to an obselete/missing nuget package, you may try to update/sync all packages used in your failing form.

Comment: There is no warning symbols from nuget and none that affect devexpress its not a nuget package its assemble and files

Comment: Then this is not related to Visual Studio, you can also log this to https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center, at this question they are saying this to convert to web app, https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q100881

Comment: @AnilKumar it is related to visual studio its to do with the build process and not devexpress the file is physically in all the correct locations and hence it is a visual studio issue