# MVC Application publish issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I publish my mvc application shows error message like this [image: Error message screenshot].Please help me to publish my application.

[image: Output window coming like this.]

Comment: I don't see an error in that screenshot. Which bit is the error, in your understanding?

Comment: Thats my problem it does not show the error.But overall status coming in red color and publish failed message is showing in out put widow like this

Comment: ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: look into your ouput window. Eventually, increase log verbosity for it

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903337/build-succeeds-but-publish-fails or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201146/visual-studio-2012-web-publish-doesnt-copy-files or https://forums.asp.net/t/1248620.aspx?Cannot+publish+the+web+site+publish+failed+ help?

Comment: As a try ,just rebuild you application and publish it again.sometime it will work. . And its seems that there plenty of warning so if possible try to solve those warning and publish.Hope it will help